# jQuery using .html & then window.scrollTo

Tags: jquery

I'm doing the following:

First, inject HTML into the page (a lot) which then increases the window scrollbar:

```
$("#XXXX").html("LOTS OF HTML").show();
```

Then i want to scroll down to the end of the page:

```
window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());
```

Problem is the page never scrolls down. I did some console.logging and the scrollTo is running before the HTML from the inject html() is run. I tried this in the JS which injects the HTML, I then tried doing the scroll inside the HTML inject but that made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the injection within an AJAX call? You can either call it after you inject, or place the scroll in a `setTimeout(...)` and give the browser time to catch up.

Comment: the injection is in an AJAX call. I want to avoid setTimeout that's a hack that always creates problems down the road.

Comment: If only .html() had a callback!  I'm pretty stumped by this but I'll think it over a bit.

Comment: Can you show some more context for your code? Your AJAX request, for instance, would be useful, particularly in relation to the position of the `scrollTo` call.

Comment: does using a table or position:relative cause issues? Also is it window.scrollTo, not HTML or BODY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try:

```
$.ajax({
       //other params
       //params
       success: function(data) {
            $("#XXXX").html(data).show();
       }
       complete: function() {
            window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());
       }
     });
```

The success function runs when the call is successful, and the complete function runs after that, so it might work!

Here's the [jQuery docs on .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Putting `window.scrollTo` in the `success` handler will be sufficient. `html` is a blocking function, as is `show` when called with no parameters, so `scrollTo` will not be called until they have executed.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, here is a different approach (in-case anyone else wants it). I've extended jQuery to add a "ScrollToBottom" function. You can place this in-line with an append/html/text function and will be called after.

The Setup:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        scrollToBottom: function(){
            window.scrollTo(0,$(document).height());
            return this; // allow chaining
        }
    });
    // alias in case you want to call it individually
    $.scrollToBottom = $(document).scrollToBottom();
})(jQuery);
```

The execution:

```
<head>
  $(function(){
      var data = '';
      for (var d = 0; d < 255; d++)
          data += '<p>Hello, world from me!</p>';

      $('#demo').html(data).scrollToBottom();
  });
</head>
<body>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

The result: [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/XgjLC/2/)

**EDIT** Added an alias to allow it to be called on its own.

Comment: I'm not convinced it makes sense to define this as `$.fn.scrollToBottom` as there is no semantic link to the element selected (I'd implement it as `$.scrollToBottom`), but +1 for some nice code.

Comment: @lonesomeday: You're absolutely right, there is no reason for it--other than to allow it to be called in-line. Allow the other functions to be called then call the scroll (also makes for easier (IMHO) calling when you've got a nice chain going)